# Remove certain commits from being merged in a certain branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have following scenarios.

I have 2 staging branches. `stage A` and `stage B`. Certain features are intended to be tested on `stage B` only and should not be merged into `stage A`.

Let's say I checked out a new feature branch `feature A` from `master`. Finished it. I pushed it on `stage B`. QA passed it. Then I merged `feature A` with `master`. And deployed it. `feature A` should not end up on `stage A`. Now I create a new feature branch `feature B` from `master`. Finished it. This is feature can be tested on `stage A`. But when I merge it with `stage A` I do not want the commits from `feature A` to be merged and pushed to `stage A` because it should not appear on `stage A` at all. How can I make this happen? Or any Git/gitlab branching strategy that would help in this scenario?

Comment: Do you have some `production` branch? Looks like you should start your feature-branches from that "stable" branch, not master.

Comment: The issue here is that you have master in the middle which will contain both sets. This is not sustainable in the manner you have chosen. My advice would be to go from having code present or not to configuring it. That is, the code would be present, but you have a configuration that tells the application whether the code applies or not. This is much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to manage this through commits in git, this would mean that the code on `stage A` would be different from the code on `stage B` or master, and IMHO become a pain to maintain afterwards -- the code you test will not be the same, the merges, the conflicts,  ...

I would suggest to handle this through code : choose some way to activate/deactivate that feature through a configuration setting of your application.

Comment: How would you approach this as far as configuration approach is followed as you mentioned? Any options in your mind?